# Typescript Sequelize associations

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, associations

I have simple 2 models in relationship 1:N -> 1 student has many tasks.

```
// StudentModel.ts
interface StudentI extends Model<InferAttributes<StudentI>, InferCreationAttributes<StudentI>> {
    id: CreationOptional<number>
    name: string
    age: number
}

const StudentModel = sequelizeConn.define<StudentI>("student", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
        allowNull: false
    },
    age: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
})

export default StudentModel
```

```
// TaksModel.ts
interface TaskI extends Model<InferAttributes<TaskI>, InferCreationAttributes<TaskI>> {
    id: CreationOptional<number>,
    student_id: number,
    definition: string
}

const TaksModel = sequelizeConn.define<TaskI>("task", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    student_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    definition: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
        allowNull: false
    }
})

export default TaksModel
```

```
// associations.ts

StudentModel.hasMany(TaksModel, { foreignKey: "student_id", as: "tasks" })
TaksModel.belongsTo(StudentModel, { foreignKey: "student_id", as: "student" })
```

Model's types alone are okay, but in relationship I have to use "any" keyword.

```
randomFile.ts

const task = await TaksModel.findOne({
    where: {
        id: 1
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: StudentModel,
            as: "student"
        }
    ]
})
// if (task.student.age == 15 ) { } -> return Property 'student' does not exist on type 'TaskI'
if ((task as any).student.age == 15 ) { //do some stuff }
```

Have someone better example how avoid "any" keyword? Because official docs deals mainly with the types of models themselves without associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a prop `student` in the model's interface like this:

```
interface TaskI extends Model<InferAttributes<TaskI>, InferCreationAttributes<TaskI>> {
    id: CreationOptional<number>,
    student_id: number,
    definition: string,
    student: NonAttribute<StudentModel>
}
```

and it seems you copy-pasted model's name here:

```
// should be define<TaskI>("task"
const TaksModel = sequelizeConn.define<StudentI>("student", {
```

The official documentation mentions how to declare association props [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/#usage). See `NonAttribute` usages.

Comment: Yes thanks, it works. And yes, I pasted StudentI by mistake :D